# How to check for any answer satisfying a condition

Tags: prolog

I have just started with Prolog and I have come to a roadblock. I have searched for an answer to this here and on google for maybe 2 hours now. Its probaly really easy and I probably missed it but I am about to give up so please help me.

I dont really know how to ask the question so here is an example.

Lets say I have this:

```
related(football, sport).
related(thing, otherthing).
related(rugby, sport).
```

I want to make a rule. One of the conditions in this rule is to check if I am related to anything.

```
rule(A) :- <Here I want to check if A is related to anything> , othercondition(A).
```

I need to know if its related to anything at all. What it is related to does not matter.

using

```
rule(rugby).
```

for example would give me true since rugby is related to sport.

I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write:

```
rule(A):-related(A,_),othercondition(A).
```

Note that '_' is anonymous variable and matches with anything.

Comment: Glad that helped!